# Saving a google spreadsheet to a pdf file font size issue

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch

I'm trying to save a google spreadsheet to a pdf file. While the code below works, the font size in the saved pdf file is minuscule. The font size can be changed in the spreadsheet with:

```
  var cell = ts.getRange('A1:E7');
  cell.setFontSize(12);
```

But ultimately, in the saved PDF, the font size is much, much smaller. The code below accomplishes what I'm trying to do with the exception of the font size issue. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```js
function savePDF() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ts = ss.getSheetByName('common');
  var cell = ts.getRange('A1:E7');
  cell.setFontSize(12);
  
  var url = Drive.Files.get(ss.getId()).exportLinks['application/pdf'];
  var sheetID=ts.getSheetId();
  url = url + '&size=letter' + //paper size
  '&portrait=true' + //orientation, false for landscape
    '&fitw=true' + //fit to width, false for actual size
      '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false' + //hide optional
        '&gridlines=false' + //false = hide gridlines
          '&gid='+sheetID+
            '&fzr=false'+ //do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
              '&top_margin=0.30'+              //All four margins must be set!
                '&bottom_margin=5.00 '+         
                  '&left_margin=5.00'+            
                    '&right_margin=0.00'+ 
                      '&horizontal_alignment=RIGHT'+
                        '&vertical_alignment=BOTTOM'; 
  

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}}).getBlob();
  DriveApp.getFolderById('URL ID is here').createFile(response).setName('testPDf');   //save the PDDF in Drive
  
}
```

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

### The pdf adjusts the font in such a way that everything fits within the width of the page.

- If you remove the margins or decrease `left_margin` - you can set a bigger font.
- Mind that `12` is not big - you might want to set a bigger font size.
- Also, make sure that your column width is adjusted correctly.